How can I send automatically email status of test plan everyday at specific time from Jira
I am wondering how can I send automatic email status of test plan (how many test cases passed, how many test cases failed) from Jira Xray?
We are using remote parallel execution from Jenkins, which automatically will communicate with Jira Xray and update status of test cases. But additionally I want to send email to manager and myself how many failures and how many test cases passed every day at specific time.
I tried "Create rules" by using smart values

To be able to help you out, can you please clarify if you are using Xray on Jira server/datacenter or Xray on Jira Cloud? Usually cloud instances are something like xxx.atlassian.net . You can also ask your Jira admin.

I am using Xray on Jira Cloud

If you're using Xray on Jira cloud, you have two options:

use Xporter app for Jira (separate plugin for Jira), that integrates with Xray, and that provides the schedule reports feature.


Install the Xray Test Plan Report template and use it in your schedule reports configuration.

Use Jira's built-in Automation capabilities

You can use Jira's automation features but it will require some work:
a) make REST API call to authenticate and obtain a token
2) make a GraphQL request to get the status of tests for the Test Plan given its issueid
3) process the answer and build the message content for the email

You can see in this code snippet the REST API calls you need to perform and adapt accordingly.
